# * or & to receive the address

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Currently I am going through an assignment for an intermediate level C++ course.  The PDF asks to create a constructor that receives the address of a string and few other parameters with different data types.  This was my attempt:

```
Passenger(const char &pName, const char &pDestination, int year, int month, int destination);
```

which I think is reasonable.  I'm always under the impression that & is what we used to retrieve the memory address of a variable.

The second constructor was already written for the student and the student is asked to just write it in the .h file.  The problem is that this constructor is returning the address of a variable but it is written like this:

```
const* char name() const
```

I'm really confused.  I am pretty novice so it's definitely my lack of understanding.  I'd appreciate it if someone could explain why the instructor is using * for a constructor that is supposed to return an address.

Comment: The person who downvoted.  Can you at least take the liberty to explain why?

Comment: `&` is used for creating a _reference_. `*` creates a pointer, which stores the  address of another object pointed to. (Not the downvoter)

Comment: He said he didn't downvote

Comment: I removed my comment.

Comment: Bare in mind: The C part of C++ is confusing for many people. This is just one of several examples of confusion. You need to be careful as you progress learning.

Comment: Thank you.  Makes a lot of sense.  If you guys think that this question was well asked, could I get an upvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol `&` has three meanings:

- as an operator, to obtain the address of an object. Ex: `&x` gives the address of `x`.
- to indicate a reference (alias) to an object. Ex: `int &x = a` says `x` is an alias to an integer named `a`.
- bitwise AND (not relevant to your question)

So when you write `const char &pName` you meant `const char *pName`. The star indicates a pointer, which is a variable used for storing an address.

Comment: Actually, at least three meanings.

Comment: @NeilButterworth what's the third

Comment: Bitwise-and operator is the 3rd meaning. Not sure if there is 4th.

Comment: Bit-wise and operator.

Comment: @NeilButterworth i have fixed it

Comment: Thank you @stackptr.  I will accept your answer in 5 minutes, as the system requires me to wait.  If you think that this question was well asked, could you give me an upvote?